# X fails to start after update

Tags: boot, lightdm

After updating ubuntu yesterday, the system boots on a dark screen (+ no signal message on monitor). Ctrl-Alt-F1 gives access to command prompt, and I tried a sudo service lightdm restart -> which gives me back a dark screen...

What should I do to solve it ? How may I reset all settings or restore to previous state, I'm ready to accept that.

Btw I also tried to boot in X mode "fail safe" from recovery menu, that failed also.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with Nvidia drivers I think, although I do not know why. This worked:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common        
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo reboot
```